# RowLayout ignores Layout.minimumWidth

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

The `text` and `text2` should be properly elided (show three dots when space is not enough to cover whole string) when the window is too small.  The `Layout.preferredWidth` is set to be `text.implicitWidth` with some addition for padding, but i even set the `Layout.minimumWidth`, so the text can be ellided when the space is not enough. It seems that the `RowLayout` is ignoring the `Layout.minimumWidth` and keeps the `Layout.preferredWidth`, so the text has still `width` of `Layout.preferredWidth` and is never elided. What's wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    contentItem.minimumWidth: 50

    RowLayout {
        id: ntoolbarline

        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"

            Layout.preferredWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            Layout.minimumWidth: 25
            Layout.minimumHeight: 25
            Layout.maximumWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40

            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Foooooooo"
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                width: parent.width - 40
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"

            Layout.preferredWidth: text2.implicitWidth + 40
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            Layout.minimumWidth: 25
            Layout.minimumHeight: 25
            Layout.maximumWidth: text2.implicitWidth + 40

            onWidthChanged: console.log("layout item width: " + width) // only one output when app started

            Text {
                id: text2
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Baaaaaaaar"
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                width: parent.width - 40
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: spacer
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            onWidthChanged: console.log("spacer width: " + width) // outputs whenever the window is resized
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems here:

1. `fillWidth` is not defined
2. `Text` is `centerIn` the parent `Rectangle`

Without 1. the `Rectangle`s cannot grow or shrink inside the desired constraints. By making  use of 2. the `Text` element as no specific constraints on its size and borders and thus `Text` cannot correctly check that an elide is required. The correct way to go is to use `fill` and setting alignments via the `verticalAlignment` and `horizontalAlignment` of `Text`.

The final revisited code looks like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    minimumWidth: 50
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        id: ntoolbarline
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            Layout.minimumWidth: 25
            Layout.maximumWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40

            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: "Foooooooo"
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            Layout.minimumWidth: 25
            Layout.maximumWidth: text.implicitWidth + 40

            Text {
                id: text2
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: "Baaaaaaaar"
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: spacer
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```